# How do I change color of interactions based on interaction value using an ifelse() statement in an plotweb bipartite?

Tags: r, if-statement, networking, bipartite

Hi I am having trouble trying to get ifelse statements to work in a plotweb fuction (from *bipartite*) to color interaction based on the total quantity of interaction of each cell in the matrix.  I had the same problem with the high bar colors, but since there were only a few values and one vector, it was easy to manually code.

Here is the code I am using, I want to color interactions greater than 15 as dark turquoise and keep the rest as default grey (grey80).

I have tried many different statements but I cant seem how to figure out what to put in the [,] to signify for the function to go through every individual cell and apply the statement instead of summing them, elem,elem also doesn't seem to work. Attached is a picture of the function's output currently

```
plotweb(LadyNet, 
        abuns.type='additional',
        arrow="up.center",
        text.rot=90,
        col.low=c("olivedrab3"),
        col.interaction =(ifelse(LadyNet[,] < 15,'grey80','darkturquoise')), 
        col.high = c("grey10","#FF0000","grey10","#FF0000","grey10","#FF0000","grey10","grey10","grey10"),
        high.lab.dis = 0,
        ybig=1.2,
        y.width.high = .06,
        high.spacing = 0.011, 
        y.lim = c(-1,2))
```

[image: Picture of Output]

```
COCCAL  COCSEP  CYCPOL  CYCSAN  EXOFAS  HIPCON  PSYVIG  SCY1    SCYMAR
Acmispon glaber 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Ambrosia psilostachya   1   36  0   24  0   6   0   0   0
Artemisia douglasiana   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
Asclepias fascicularis  0   5   0   4   0   2   0   0   0
Avena fatua 6   10  0   0   0   4   0   0   0
Baccharis pilularis 9   76  0   38  0   27  0   1   0
Baccharis salicifolia   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Bromus diandrus 1   8   0   0   0   4   0   0   0
Capsicum annuum 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
Chenopodium murale  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Croton californicus 3   20  0   13  0   54  4   0   0
DEAD WOOD   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Distichilis spicata 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Echium candicans    0   1   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
Eleocharis acicularis   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Encelia californica 1   1   0   3   0   2   0   0   0
Epilobium canum 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Erigeron bonariensis    0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Erigeron canadensis 0   17  0   10  0   2   0   0   0
Erigeron sumatrensis    0   13  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Eriophyllum confertiflorum  1   10  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Fence   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Festuca perennis    0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
Gambelium speciosa  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Geranium dissectum  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
GROUND  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Helminthotheca echioides    0   1   2   17  0   1   0   0   0
Heterotheca grandiflora 2   92  0   12  0   7   1   0   0
Hirschfieldia incana    0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Juncus patens   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Laennecia coulteri  1   65  0   2   0   3   0   0   0
Lobularia maritima  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Morus sp.   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
NoPicture   4   3   0   3   3   2   3   0   0
Oxalis pes-caprae   4   6   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
Pennisetum clandestinum 1   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Polygonum arenastrum    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Raphanus sativus    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ROCK    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Rumex crispus   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Rumex salicifolius  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
Salsola tragus  1   6   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
Salvia leucophylla  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Schenoplectus americanus    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Solanum nigrum  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Sonchus arvensis    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Spinacia oleracea   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
Stipa pulchra   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Symphiotrichum subulatum    0   88  0   7   0   3   0   0   0
THATCH  1   3   0   0   0   4   0   0   0
Verbena lasiostachys    1   9   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
```

For Reference, I have gotten the ifelse statement to function properly in the plotweb function when there was only one species in the lower level attached is an example along with the code:

[image: RNET]

```
plotweb(rnet, 
        abuns.type='additional',
        arrow="down.center",
        text.rot=90,  
        col.low=c("olivedrab3"),
        col.interaction =(ifelse(rnet[1,] < 12,'grey80','darkturquoise')), 
        col.high = (ifelse(rnet[1,] < 12,'grey10','darkturquoise')),
        high.lab.dis = 0,
        ybig=1.2,
        y.width.high = .06, 
        high.spacing = 0.011)
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing at least some of `LadyNet`.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for fixing the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that the `col.interaction` color matrix should be transposed.

Here is an example that I trust you will find useful:

```
library(bipartite)
library(grDevices)

plotweb(df, 
    abuns.type='additional',
    arrow="up.center",
    text.rot=90,
    col.low=c("olivedrab3"),
    col.interaction = t(ifelse(df[,] < 15,
                             adjustcolor('grey80', alpha.f = 0.5), #add alpha to colors
                             adjustcolor('darkturquoise', alpha.f = 0.5))), 
    col.high = c("grey10",
                 "#FF0000",
                 "grey10",
                 "#FF0000",
                 "grey10",
                 "#FF0000",
                 "grey10",
                 "grey10",
                 "grey10"),
    bor.col.interaction = NA, #remove the black border color
    high.lab.dis = 0,
    ybig=1.2,
    y.width.high = .06,
    high.spacing = 0.011, 
    y.lim = c(-1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi missuse,Thank you for your help, this code helps definitely, removing the borders and adding alpha was a good idea, but I still am having the same issue. I am not sure how you decided to select the value 2 for the if else statement, but to me it still seems like it is being colored randomly. My biggest issue right now is that I am trying to get the if else statement to work to color the interaction based on their value, so if interaction > 15, (yes) color darkturquoise, (no) color grey80

Comment: @Justin Luong you are correct, I had not checked in detail when I gave the answer. I trust this update will be more satisfying.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! If you don't mind me asking for my own learning purposes, what exactly does the grDevices package do and the t() function in front of the ifelse statement do?

Comment: @Justin Luong the `t` (base R) performs a matrix transpose (flips the matrix around the diagonal so columns become rows and rows become columns - this is how the input data for this argument should look like). The `adjustcolor` function is from `grDevices` it adds transparency to a color. Glad to help.